# jQuery image slider buttons are repositioning themselves

Tags: jquery, anythingslider

I have an AnythingSlider (jQuery image slider) at [Connected Ventures](http://www.connected-ventures.com) and, when the page loads, the two central navigation buttons (active and inactive slide) move up about 10px after a second. I have scrutinised the code for any conflicting margins or positioning but can't see anything wrong.

The AnythingSlider works fine the [other site](http://www.spiritdigital.co.uk/F8/index.html) that it's being used and I even copied and pasted the code from the anythingslider.css of this page to the page with the problem, but it didn't fix it.

I'm out of ideas, any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: The issue happens in latest Chrome, Safari, and IE, but NOT in Firefox.

Comment: even in Firefox 12.0, I have the same problem!

Comment: It seems the div.anythingControls which is created by the JS to contain the two active/inactive buttons is the container which is out of place, rather than the buttons per se.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a top margin that isn't being cleared. Try adding this css:

```
div.anythingSlider .anythingControls ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 25px 0 0 329px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, although this didn't solve the problem directly it did lead me to a solution.  I added the ul margin to the anythingslider.css and it moved the buttons down further but so they settled in the correct place. I then change the height of the main slider and all was fixed. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the height of the div? E.G?

`$('#slider').anythingSlider({height: 308});`

Comment: The dimensions of the AnythingSlider are set within the CSS file so not sure if this would help unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the height of your anything slider to 308px, that will work fine I guess.

```
 <div class="anythingSlider anythingSlider-default activeSlider" style="width: 620px; height: 308px;">
```

Comment: I believe the dimensions are set within the anythingslider.css as #slider { width: 620px; height: 308px; }

Comment: Dont you have this code in your HTML: 
    <div class="anythingSlider anythingSlider-default activeSlider" style="width: 620px; height: 299px;">

Comment: That code is generated by the javascript using the dimensions specified in the CSS, so it's not in the HTML document until the document loads.